# glCreateProgram returns weird ids on LG7?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

Im getting weird compatibility issues when programing opengl es 2.0 using c++ (NDK).
When I run the code on a Nexus5 and it works just fine, when I create the shader programs glCreateProgram returns correct ids (3,6 and 9 for the first 3 programs).

But, when I run the same code on LG7, the glCreateProgram returns the same numbers with an adition of (7*x*10000) making the first shaders 210003, 420006 and 630009. This way, the program does not work (the shaders doesn't work, but I get no errors on shader compilation).

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier returned by `glCreateProgram` is implementation-defined. You shouldn't be relying on any particular value being returned. From the [doc](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCreateProgram.xml):

> `glCreateProgram` creates an empty program object and returns a non-zero value by which it can be referenced.

So, keep track of the returned value and use that in subsequent code to refer to your shader.

Comment: i do it this way, and it works on the nexus, windows, raspberry, and debian linux (is a multiplatform project). But, it doesnt work on the LG7, and the only difference are those ids, so i thought it was something about them... any clue?

Comment: The IDs are almost certainly not your problem. Check your shader compile and link logs, and the result of `glGetError` after every call. If that all seems fine, try stripping down your shader to see if the shader compiler is breaking you silently; not all OpenGL drivers are good at producing useful error messages.

Comment: Every GLES implementation is a little bit different in terms of what shaders it will accept, so it's not unheard-of for shaders to work fine on one device and fail completely on another.  Remember that `glCompileShader()` does *not* set the `glGetError()` value; you must check the function return value, then use `glGetShaderInfoLog()` to see the problem.